# array.indexof multidimensional array with unknown key

Tags: javascript, html

so I have a multidimensional array. I want to get the key of one of the sub arrays, given a value.

```
var MyArr = [];
MyArr[0] = ['cat','black',5]
MyArr[1] = ['dog','red',7]
MyArr[2] = ['pig','blue',4]
```

what I want to be able to do is use a value say 'blue' and have it return the key of 2
so that I could take that 2 and do something like
MyArr[2][0] to get 'pig'

I couldn't quite get indexof to work correctly.

any thoughts?

Also has to be pure JS cannot use JQuery

Comment: If you always have exact same number of elements in all nested array then you can also use `Math.floor(
  MyArr.flat().findIndex((val) => val === "blue") / MyArr.length
);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, using [`Array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const arr = [
  ['cat','black',5],
  ['dog','red',7],
  ['pig','blue',4]
];

let i = arr.findIndex(a => a.includes('blue'));

console.log(i)
```